# Failed to parse gcp.yml with gcp_compute plugin

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ansible, service-accounts, terraform-provider-gcp

I am creating ansible playbook to configure VM's in GCP. I am making use of `gcp_compute` plugin to build a dynamic inventory. Using service account with role `roles\editor` to authenticate with google cloud. Playbook fails with below error when executed.

```
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse gcp.yml with gcp_compute plugin: [{'message': "Required 'compute.instances.list' permission for 'projects/project-dev-295204'", 'domain':
'global', 'reason': 'forbidden'}]
[WARNING]: gcp.yml as an inventory source
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
```

As per the warning message it looks like the service account does not have necessary permissions to generate a list of running VM instances to build the inventory, but the services account has role `editor` attached to it and this role has all required privileges to edit, list most of resources in GCP.

### ansible.cfg

```
[defaults]
roles_path = roles
inventory = gcp.yml
remote_user = ansible
host_key_checking = False
private_key_file = $GOOGLE_SSH_KEY

[inventory]
enable_plugins = gcp_compute
```

### gcp.yml

```
plugin: gcp_compute
projects:
  - project-dev-295204

auth_kind: serviceaccount
service_account_file: $GOOGLE_SA

keyed_groups:
  - key: labels
    prefix: label
  - key: zone
    prefix: zone
```

### Workaround

The playbook returned successful response after **service account was added as IAM member** & mapped to role `roles\Editor`in the IAM Admin home page.

Below commands returned 403 response `(authentication mode = service account)` until the service account was added as a new IAM member.

```
gcloud compute instances list
gcloud compute addresses list
```

How does attaching a role to the service account while creating it `vs` adding the service account as an IAM member and tagging it to the same role make a difference.

### Note (Edit 1):

I created service account through terraform using resource type `google_service_account` to create a service account and `google_service_account_iam_policy` to attach editor role to the service account.

Comment: Could you please confirm if the Service Account that you are using is under the same project where you are executing the commands?
When you create a SA with a role, in your case `roles\Editor` it will automatically be in IAM. IF you are using a different project the SA won’t be able to execute the commands because it doesn't have the correct permissions in that other project.

Comment: Yes, the project is same. I created SA through terraform attached editor role to it then verified that the service account was part of editors pool. Ran playbook but it did not work so to make it work, I had to explicitly add the service account as an IAM member and assign it to editors pool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using [IAM policy for service account](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/google_service_account_iam) this means that it will set IAM bindings to resource level meaning you are setting editor role for SA my-sa@ on the same service account not on the actual project level. Please avoid using [google_service_account_iam_policy](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/google_service_account_iam#google_service_account_iam_policy) since it overrides existing bindings and will only set `serviceAccount`, `user`, `group`, etc. and their respective roles that were specified in your TF file.

In order to ***"add"*** a binding and not ***"set"*** at project level, you'll need to use the following [google_project_iam_binding](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/google_project_iam#google_project_iam_binding) for updating existing bindings if this is the first time creating a binding then use [google_project_iam_member](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/google_project_iam#google_project_iam_member) , this will not override your existing bindings at project level.

Keep in mind that if you do a ***"set"*** IAM binding you can potentially be locked out of project. Please take a look at the following documentations as well to get a better understanding for [IAM policy for projects](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/google_project_iam)

Comment: thank you for much clearer and elaborative explanation.